# Show that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

$\frac{2}{3}x^5 + \frac{1}{2}x^4 -2x^2 + \frac{1}{2}$.

I know that I have to use Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion, but how do I apply it with coefficients that are fractions?

Comment: Clear the denominators so it becomes a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that $$6f(x) = 4x^5 + 3x^4 - 12x^2 + 3$$